# seperate number prints for two or more digits

Tags: python, list, numbers

So I have made a collatz calculator for fun (if you dont know what it is look it up), and I wanted to record how many steps it takes to reach 1, then put that data into a list. whenever there is a number with more than 2 digits, it separates the digits into two different spots on the list.

This is the code

```
steps = 0
stepsList = []
numList = []
listCount = 0

while True:
    numIn = int(input('enter number: '))
    while True:
        if numIn % 2 == 0:
            numIn = numIn / 2
        else:
            numIn = (3 * numIn) + 1
        print(numIn)
        steps += 1
        if numIn == 1:
            numIn += 1
            print('~~~')
            print(str(steps) + ' steps')
            stepsList.extend(str(steps))
            print(stepsList)
            break
```

and say i put in the number 27, instead of it storing it as [111], it stores it as [1,1,1]

Comment: Use `stepsList.append(steps)`. `extend` takes an iterable and concats them on the back of the list. I'm not sure why you're converting to a string in any event--what is the output you need overall?

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the following lines:

```
            print(str(steps) + ' steps')
            stepsList.extend(str(steps))
```

by

```
            print(steps, 'steps')
            stepsList.append(steps)
```

and maybe you should also reset the `steps` counter at the beginning of the external loop, if you need the number of steps for each different test number, instead of a cumulative counter...

Comment: that worked, but now whenever a new number is added, its just the sum of the last number plus the steps. 
IE if the first in the list is 5 steps, then the next one is 4, the second thing on the list will be 9 instead of 4

Comment: @duff78: as I said at the end of my answer : you have to reset the `steps` counter, for each new test number. Simply add `steps = 0` after the first `while True`

Answer (score 0):

```
stepsList = []

while True:
    try:
        numIn = int(input('enter number: '))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

    steps = 0

    while True:
        if numIn % 2 == 0:
            numIn = numIn / 2
        else:
            numIn = (3 * numIn) + 1
        # print(numIn)
        steps += 1
        if numIn == 1:
            numIn += 1
            print('~~~')
            print(str(steps) + ' steps')
            stepsList.append(steps)
            print(stepsList)
            break
```

Added some cleanup & better ctrl-c handling :)

Looks good to me

```
enter number: 27
~~~
111 steps
[111]
enter number: 1
~~~
3 steps
[111, 3]
enter number: 4
~~~
2 steps
[111, 3, 2]
enter number: 6
~~~
8 steps
[111, 3, 2, 8]
enter number: 10
~~~
6 steps
[111, 3, 2, 8, 6]
enter number: ^C%
```